# An example of a ring of formal power series with a certain property

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

On page 118 of Matsumura it is said that it is not true in general that $A[[X]]\otimes_A k(\mathfrak p)$ is isomorphic to $k(\mathfrak p)[[X]]$ where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $A$ and $k(\mathfrak p)=A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$. Could you give me an example?

Comment: *Which* Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory* or *Commutative Algebra*?

Comment: commutative ring theory

Comment: See my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274803

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I see now why Matsumura's book has to mean that the isomorphism must be the canonical one.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=\mathbb Z$ and $\mathfrak p=(0)$. Then one has to prove that $\mathbb Z[[X]]\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[[X]]$. In order to do this note first that $\mathbb Z[[X]]\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$ is isomorphic to the fraction ring  $S^{-1}\mathbb Z[[X]]$, where $S=\mathbb Z-\{0\}$. The ring $\mathbb Q[[X]]$ is local, while $S^{-1}\mathbb Z[[X]]$ is not.

Comment: One can also observe that $\sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{-n}X^n\in \mathbb Q[[X]]$ is not in $\mathbb Z[[X]]\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ because the latter only contains formal powers series with bounded denominators.

Comment: @QiL An isomorphism could be different from the canonical one.

Comment: But of course Matsumura means that the canonical map $A[[X]] \otimes_A K \to K[[X]]$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg How do you know this? I've checked the book and he says exactly what the OP has written above.

Comment: Anyway I upvoted the answer because it proves there is no isomorphism at all.

Comment: +1 How can we see that $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ is not local?

Comment: @Manos The prime ideals of $S^{-1}\mathbb Z[[X]]$ correspond to the prime ideals of $\mathbb Z[[X]]$ lying over $(0)$ and it's easily seen that there are many prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[[X]]$ with this property (and not containing each other), e.g., $(X)$, $(2+X)$.